# Copy and Paste Values, Searching all at once, whilst preserving the Formula's

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to this and I'm pretty surprised I got this far I have been able to look at some code I got given from another spreadsheet so a little help there, but now I'm a little stuck.

Below is a code for a simple copy values to another sheet whilst keep everything in check like the formulas in the original sheet it copied from. I'd link this to a button, The problem with this method is that

1. I'm going to have to create multiple buttons for this and edit the code accordingly.
2. When everything is good and I hit the button to move the data, I'm going to have to repeat this process multiple times if I have a lot of rows with data on.

Ideally I'd like to have a similar code from below but just have 1 button that I press once and search for the word "Pending" in Column J in each row if said row has "Pending" Just leave it alone. If not then run the code below.

I think I've explained that ok please let me know or ask anything. Again very new to this so please keep that in mind and hopefully the code show's up ok.

Thanks in Advance!

```
Sub CopySource()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Range("J1").Value = "Pending" Then
MsgBox "Result still set as 'Pending'. Not Complete."
Else
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngTarget As Range
Dim iRow As Integer

iRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L1").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & iRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Dim rConstants As Range

Set rConstants = Sheet1.Range("A1:L1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
rConstants.ClearContents
Range("J1").FormulaR1C1 = "Pending"

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: You can either loop, use Find or Autofilter which avoids a loop altogether.

Comment: So what you do now is that you change al the references to row 1 in sheet1 in order to copy the right row?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First use it on a copy of your current workbook to make sure it doesn't do unexpected things.

```
Sub CopySource()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim last As Long
Dim rngSource As Range
Dim rngTarget As Range
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim rConstants As Range

last = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To last
    If Range("J" & i).Value <> "Pending" Then
        iRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":L" & i).Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & iRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Set rConstants = Sheet1.Range("A" & i & ":L" & i).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        rConstants.ClearContents
        Range("J" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "Pending"
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (optimizations omitted for clarity):

```vb
Sub CopySource()

    Dim c As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    For Each c In wsSrc.Range("J1:J" & wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If Not c.Value = "Pending" Then
            Set rng = c.EntireRow.Range("A1:L1") 'range is *relative* to the row...
            With wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Resize(1, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value
            End With
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
            c.Value = "Pending"
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: I was just coding a very similar solution up, but I'm too slow. :)
 SJ789, Tim's solution is exactly what you're after and I nominate it as the answer.